# Javascript: Split a string by comma, except inside parentheses

Tags: javascript, parsing

Given string in the form:

```
'"abc",ab(),c(d(),e()),f(g(),zyx),h(123)'
```

How can I split it to get the below array format:

```
abc
ab()
c(d(),e())
f(g(),zyx)
h(123)
```

I have tried normal javascript split, however it doesn't work as desired. Trying Regular Expression but not yet successful.

Comment: Neither plain `split()` nor regular expressions can solve this -- obviously you don't just want to split on comma, else you wouldn't have expected the result you listed here. Seems like you will need to write a proper parser. A simple recursive descent one would do the job pretty well.

Comment: In what way did it not work as expected? Are we supposed to read your mind?

Comment: Please re-word your question title, maybe it will stop the downvotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep track of the parentheses, and add those expressions when the left and right parens equalize.

For example-

```
function splitNoParen(s){
    var left= 0, right= 0, A= [], 
    M= s.match(/([^()]+)|([()])/g), L= M.length, next, str= '';
    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        next= M[i];
        if(next=== '(')++left;
        else if(next=== ')')++right;
        if(left!== 0){
            str+= next;
            if(left=== right){
                A[A.length-1]+=str;
                left= right= 0;
                str= '';
            }
        }
        else A=A.concat(next.match(/([^,]+)/g));
    }
    return A;
}

var s1= '"abc",ab(),c(d(),e()),f(g(),zyx),h(123)';
splitNoParen(s1).join('\n');

/*  returned value: (String)
"abc"
ab()
c(d(),e())
f(g(),zyx)
h(123)
*/
```

Comment: We went through the same principle, posted our answers around the same time, but your answer looks way more _sophisticated_. :)

Comment: The answer doesn't quite work in all cases. It fails with the string `'cats,(my-foo)-bar,baz'` which should return three elements, `cats`, `(my-foo)-bar`, and `baz`. But instead it returns `cats(my-foo)`, `-bar`, and `baz`. See my solution instead.

Answer (score 5):

This might be not the best or more *refined* solution, and also maybe won't fit every single possibility, but based on your example it works:

```
var data = '"abc",ab(),c(d(),e()),f(g(),zyx),h(123)';
// Create a preResult splitting the commas.
var preResult = data.replace(/"/g, '').split(',');
// Create an empty result.
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < preResult.length; i++) {
    // Check on every preResult if the number of parentheses match.
    // Opening ones...
    var opening = preResult[i].match(/\(/g) || 0;
    // Closing ones...
    var closing = preResult[i].match(/\)/g) || 0;

    if (opening != 0 &&
        closing != 0 &&
        opening.length != closing.length) {
        // If the current item contains a different number of opening
        // and closing parentheses, merge it with the next adding a 
        // comma in between.
        result.push(preResult[i] + ',' + preResult[i + 1]);
        i++;
    } else {
        // Leave it as it is.
        result.push(preResult[i]);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n5nc9/)

Comment: When you get more comfortable around `Javascript`, you can use the code posted by @kennebec.

Comment: Sure, Currently going through both the answers .

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, here's another approach to top-level splitting, using `string.replace` as a control flow operator:

```
function psplit(s) {
  var depth = 0, seg = 0, rv = [];
  s.replace(/[^(),]*([)]*)([(]*)(,)?/g,
            function (m, cls, opn, com, off, s) {
    depth += opn.length - cls.length;
    var newseg = off + m.length;
    if (!depth && com) {
      rv.push(s.substring(seg, newseg - 1));
      seg = newseg;
    }
    return m;
  });
  rv.push(s.substring(seg));
  return rv;
}

console.log(psplit('abc,ab(),c(d(),e()),f(g(),zyx),h(123)'))

["abc", "ab()", "c(d(),e())", "f(g(),zyx)", "h(123)"]
```

Getting it to handle quotes as well would not be too complicated, but at some point you need to decide to use a real parser such as `jison`, and I suspect that would be the point. In any event, there's not enough detail in the question to know what the desired handling of double quotes is.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `.split` for this, but instead you'll have to write a small parser like this:

```js
function splitNoParen(s){
  let results = [];
  let next;
  let str = '';
  let left = 0, right = 0;

  function keepResult() {
    results.push(str);
    str = '';
  }

  for(var i = 0; i<s.length; i++) {
    switch(s[i]) {
    case ',': 
      if((left === right)) {
        keepResult();
        left = right = 0;
      } else {
        str += s[i];
      }
      break;
    case '(':
      left++;
      str += s[i];
      break;
    case ')':
      right++;
      str += s[i];
      break;
    default: 
      str += s[i];
    }
  }
  keepResult();
  return results;
}
  
var s1= '"abc",ab(),c(d(),e()),f(g(),zyx),h(123)';
console.log(splitNoParen(s1).join('\n'));

var s2='cats,(my-foo)-bar,baz';
console.log(splitNoParen(s2).join('\n'));
```

Comment: Thank you! This works and is so much easier to port to other languages than cryptic regex patterns (e.g. haxe regex matching is slightly different to javascript matching).

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and existing solutions were hard to generalize. So here's another parser that's a bit more readable and easier to extend to your personal needs. It'll also work with curly braces, brackets, normal braces, and strings of any type.  License is MIT.

```
/**
 * This function takes an input string and splits it by the given token, but only if the token is not inside 
 * braces of any kind, or a string.
 * @param {string} input The string to split.
 * @param {string} split_by Must be a single character.
 * @returns {string[]} An array of split parts without the split_by character. 
 */
export function parse_split(input:string, split_by:string = ",") : string[]
{
    // Javascript has 3 types of strings
    const STRING_TYPES = ["'","`","\""] as const;

    // Some symbols can be nested, like braces, and must be counted
    const state = {"{":0,"[":0,"(":0};
    // Some cannot be nested, like a string, and just flip a flag.
    // Additionally, once the string flag has been flipped, it can only be unflipped
    // by the same token.
    let string_state : (typeof STRING_TYPES)[number] | undefined = undefined

    // Nestable symbols come in sets, usually in pairs.
    // These sets increase or decrease the state, depending on the symbol.
    const pairs : Record<string,[keyof typeof state,number]> = {
        "{":["{",1],
        "}":["{",-1],
        "[":["[",1],
        "]":["[",-1],
        "(":["(",1],
        ")":["(",-1]
    }

    let start = 0;
    let results = [];
    let length = input.length;
    for(let i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        let char = input[i];

        // Backslash escapes the next character. We directly skip 2 characters by incrementing i one extra time.
        if(char === "\\")
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        // If the symbol exists in the single/not nested state object, flip the corresponding state flag.
        if(char == string_state)
        {
            string_state = undefined;
            console.log("Closed string ", string_state);
        }
        // if it's not in a string, but it's a string opener, remember the string type in string_state.
        else if(string_state === undefined && STRING_TYPES.includes(char as typeof STRING_TYPES[number]))
        {
            string_state = char as typeof STRING_TYPES[number];
        }
        // If it's not in a string, and if it's a paired symbol, increase or decrease the state based on our "pairs" constant.
        else if(string_state === undefined && (char in pairs) )
        {
            let [key,value] = pairs[char];
            state[key] += value;
        }
        // If it's our split symbol...
        else if(char === split_by)
        {
            // ... check whether any flags are active ...
            if(Object.entries(state).every(([k,v])=>v == 0) && (string_state === undefined))
            {
                // ... if not, then this is a valid split.
                results.push(input.substring(start,i))
                start = i+1;
            }
        }
    }

    // Add the last segment if the string didn't end in the split_by symbol, otherwise add an empty string
    if(start < input.length)
    {
        results.push(input.substring(start,input.length))
    }
    else
        results.push("");

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With this regex, it makes the job:

```js
const regex = /,(?![^(]*\))/g;
const str = '"abc",ab(),c(d(),e()),f(g(),zyx),h(123)';
const result = str.split(regex);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -3):

**Javascript**

```
var str='"abc",ab(),c(d(),e()),f(g(),zyx),h(123)'
str.split('"').toString().split(',').filter(Boolean);
```

this should work

Comment: Nope; this just outputs `["abc", "ab()", "c(d()", "e())", "f(g()", "zyx)", "h(123)"]`

Comment: that is an array now you can access the elements from that using for loop

Comment: Yes, but that's not what the asker wanted. Did you read the question?

Comment: I think this is exactly what is causing problem to OP. You are splitting in "," in say c(d(),e()) as well. What I can understand from OP s question is, OP wants that c(d(),e()) as a different part